# Disable vimdiff syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, neovim

I have `syntax off` at the end of my nvim.init file, but no matter how hard I try there is always diffsplit coloring.

I would like to disable it because I guess (Neo)vim is very slow with syntax highlighting enabled of files of the size I would like to diff.

Comment: I'm curious why you wrote "I guess". Do you have any reason to believe that Vim actually is slow because it is highlighting diffs, or are you just worried that it might be?

Comment: I believe it is at least partly due to highlighting as one suggestion to speed up vim on large files is to disable syntax highlighting.

Comment: You've already done that, though. I believe the slow part of syntax highlighting is the regular-expression-based matching, and diff uses a different mechanism. I've never heard that diff-colouring is slow (although I admittedly don't have any evidence that it's *not*). If diffing large files is slower than just displaying them, for you, my hunch would be that it's the processing of the diff that makes it slow, rather than the colouring of the diff results. (Again, I have no evidence to support this.)